# Python: reading ID3v1 tag with Kaitai Struct

Tags: python, id3, kaitai-struct

I'm trying to get Kaitai Struct to parse a ID3v1 tag format for MP3s. According to the [standard](http://id3.org/ID3v1), it is a fixed format structure located at the certain offset - but the trick is that this offset is calculated not from the beginning of the file, but from the end.

Here's the basic `.ksy` outline of the tag, I take it for granted that it shouldn't really change:

```
meta:
  id: id3v1
types:
  id3v1_tag:
    seq:
      - id: magic
        contents: 'TAG'
      - id: title
        size: 30
      - id: artist
        size: 30
      - id: album
        size: 30
      - id: year
        size: 4
      - id: comment
        size: 30
      - id: genre
        type: u1
```

and here's my naïve idea on how to get it to be read from the 128 bytes till the end of the file:

```
instances:
  tag:
    pos: -128
    type: id3v1_tag
```

I try that with a simple Python test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from id3v1 import *

f = Id3v1.from_file('some_file_with_id3.mp3')
print(f.tag)
```

However, it seems to pass that negative amount directly into the Python's File object `seek()` and thus fails:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "try-id3.py", line 6, in
>   
>       print(f.id3v1_tag)   File "id3v1_1.py", line 171, in id3v1_tag
>       self._io.seek(-128)   File "kaitaistruct.py", line 29, in seek
>       self._io.seek(n) IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

After a few other equally insane ideas, I've found a workaround: I can just omit any `pos` arguments in `.ksy` and then I manually seek to the proper position in my script:

```
f = Id3v1.from_file('some_file_with_id3.mp3')
f._io.seek(-128, 2)
print(f.tag.title)
```

This works, but feels really hackish :( Is there a better way to do it in Kaitai Struct and Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new feature in upcoming v0.4 of Kaitai Struct that addresses exactly this issue. You can use `_io` to get current stream object and then you can use `.size` to get full length of current stream in bytes. Thus, if you'd want to address some structure by a fixed offset from the end of the stream, you'd want to use something like in your .ksy:

```
instances:
  tag:
    pos: _io.size - 128
    type: id3v1_tag
```

Note that while current stable is v0.3, you'll have to download and build the compiler + runtimes from the Github and use the latest ones.

Comment: Thanks! That might solve it just fine! I've tried [REPL](http://kaitai.io/repl) - it reports v0.4, but it seems that it does not support `_io.size` though. Is it just me or there's some kind of error there?

Comment: Yeah, it's not yet updated. Stay tuned for v0.4 release, it should hopefully happen this week.

Comment: v0.4 is out! Feel free to check!